# Change Google Cloud SQL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP time zone?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I'm using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in Google Cloud SQL and according to [Google](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=it), it returns the server's current time.

Currently, with the time that it returns, it looks like the server's at UTC -1 (i.e., in the Atlantic Ocean). This is not very helpful.

How do I change the timezone and have it display the right time (i.e., a time zone of my own choosing) whenever I call `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 19):

There is a new way to to change Google cloud SQL time zone
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29758598/4121388

Instructions: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags

1. Go to the Google Developers Console.
2. Create a new Developers Console project, or open an existing project
   by clicking on the project name.
3. In the sidebar on the left, click Storage > Cloud SQL to show a list
   of Cloud SQL instances for the project.
4. Open your instance and click Edit. If you need to create a new
   instance, click New instance.
5. Scroll down to the MySQL Flags section.
6. Choose flags from the drop-down menu and set their values.
7. Click Save. You can check your flags under MySQL Flags on the
   overview page.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks.

Comment: I do not see the `time_zone` flag for the system zone available there.  It has `default_time_zone` only, which is the global zone.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL sets the system time as UTC.

You can set the timezone for an individual session with a statement like:

```
SET @@session.time_zone='-07:00';
```

You can use named (and daylight savings aware) timezones such as "US/Pacific" if you first set up the timezone table by running a system command like:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -h YOUR_INSTANCE_IP -u root -p mysql
```

Comment: Just some thoughts on how one might run mysql_tzinfo_to_sql on a cloud SQL instance. mysql_tzinfo_to_sql doesn't appear to exist, but /usr/share/zoneinfo does. It looks like one could apt install mysql-server-5.5 (the Debian package that contains mysq_tzinfo_to_sql). I'm not sure how to clean up after this and destroy the cloud shell files though.