# Google Cloud SQL and time zones

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I'm developing an app that meant to run only in **Israel**.
All of our tables contains times at Israeli time (**Tel Aviv** time).

because the **SQL** in **GCP** doesn't support default **timezone** and time zone convert I got stuck.

how can I convert times between time zones?

let me remind you that Israel has a **light saving** time change.

Comment: Look at [this Post][1] for all about mysql Time Zones.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Answer (score 8):

Now you have the ability to set the time zone in Cloud SQL. See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags. The limitation is that the time zone needs to be specified as offsets to UTC, such as '+10:00'. It does not support named time zones like 'Europe/Helsinki'.

Comment: So this means one have to do the Daylight Saving Time manually?

Comment: @RazvanGrigore yes, unfortunately. This is a known issue at this time. My team is currently having to switch the default_time_zone during DST. We're hoping to get it into UTC soon so we don't have to do this.

_"Automatic adjustment to daylight savings time is not supported; you must update the default_time_zone flag manually to account for daylight savings time."_
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/known-issues#administrative_issues

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL now supports named time zones. See a list here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#timezone-names

> When using timezone names, automatic adjustment to daylight saving time is supported.

What is weird is that even though when explaining named time zones it gives the example `Europe/London`, in the actual list that's missing. The closest equivalent is `Europe/Dublin`, which is functionally the same although their summer time is considered "standard" so they switch to winter time.

Answer (score -1):

**THIS ANSWER IS OBSOLETE**

On Google Cloud SQL you cannot currently set your own time zone. If you need to change the time zone on your instance, please get in touch with cloud-sql@google.com.

Comment: you dont have to mail anyone...  @Tony Tseng solutions works fine

Comment: Yep, we introduced the time zone flag Tony refers to in April, after my comment. This answer is obsolete.